# Flask-Pymongo requesting database

Tags: flask, jinja2, pymongo

I'm using PyMongo but I can't get the right syntax to POST the data from the HTML to my NOSQL DB.

This code is from a tutorial in flask:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?, ?)',
                 [request.form['title'], request.form['text']])
    db.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

This is my code:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    title = request.form['title']
    text = request.form['text']
    g.pymongo_db.insert({
        'title': title,
        'text': text
    })
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

And here is `show_entries.html`, exactly the same at tutorial:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  {% if session.logged_in %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
      <dl>
        <dt>Title:
        <dd><input type=text size=30 name=title>
        <dt>Text:
        <dd><textarea name=text rows=5 cols=40></textarea>
        <dd><input type=submit value=Share>
      </dl>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
  <ul class=entries>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>{{ entry.text|safe }}
  {% else %}
    <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Everything seems correct so far. You should post the code for `show_entries` view. Are you properly passing the `entries` variable to jinja template?

Comment: This is what debug show when i try to insert in db.

-TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.- and the problem start in 'text': text

About the entries variable in jinja template its all ok i think...

Comment: i feel like a idiot, i just change g.pymongo_db.insert

to db.posts.insert and its done where posts its my database dam, i will erase this question :)

Comment: If you are using pymongo aka mongodb, why you dont use document-oriented database ?